# Powershell: How to include conditional evaluation for get-service from input file if value is incorrect.

Tags: powershell-2.0

I wrote the script below. It works great. However I've missed an important step. To evaluate if the servicename is: wrong/mispelled. I've already captured one these mispellings and would like to add logic in my script to handle it. 
Here's my script. thanks

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$Services = Import-Csv '\\wnp6636\d$\Scripts\ProdList(1).csv' | foreach-object {$_}
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
foreach ($Serve in $Services) {
get-service -computername $Serve.Server -name      $Serve.Services,$Serve.Services_A,$Serve.Services_B,$Serve.Services_C,`
    $Serve.Services_D,$Serve.Services_E,$Serve.Services_F,$Serve.Services_G,$Serve.Services_H |`
foreach-object {if($_.Status -eq "Stopped")`
{write-host $Serve.Server $_.Displayname $_.Status -Fore "Red"}
else
{write-host $Serve.Server $_.Displayname $_.Status -Fore "Green"}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand what you are wanting...

switch might be easier to work with?

```
switch($_.status)
{
 "Stopped"{whatever code you want when it matches stopped;break}
 "Running"{whatever code you want when it matches running:break}
 Default{whatever code you want when it matches none of expected results:break}
}
```

so get rid of the if and else and feed the switch with your for loop

you could get as fancy as you want with it. also (i think $services is an array) if so then you could just feed the array to a do loop containing the get-services then use switch

hope i have not wasted your time
good luck

just realized you might need a bit more help with the default
{read-host "No such service found:Please check spelling and try again"}
that should get you there